# JavaFX BorderPane Replacing contents of Center pane are not filling pane

Tags: layout, javafx, borderpane

I am creating an app that has a main BorderPane with a menubar in the TOP. I want to change the CENTER content when a specific menu option is selected. However, when I do this, the AnchorPane that I load into the CENTER pane is not resizing to fill the CENTER pane. It keeps it's preferred size. I have tried setting it to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, but that does not resize it to fill the CENTER pane. I also tried to add an HBOX as a wrapper around the AnchorPane (I am fairly new to JavaFX UI design) which also did not work.

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPane" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="980.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  
    fx:controller="fileinventory.ApplicationFrameController">

<top><MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">...</MenuBar></top>
<center><AnchorPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" /></center>
</BorderPane>
```

I load the pane to set in the CENTER using the following call from the main class:

```
public void viewClients() {
    ViewClientsController dlg = 
            new ViewClientsController(this.bundle, this.rootLayout);
}
```

And the actual controller for the AnchorPane being loaded to the CENTER pane.

```
public class ViewClientsController {

public ViewClientsController(ResourceBundle bundle, BorderPane layout) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = 
        new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ViewClients.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    fxmlLoader.setResources(bundle);

    try {
        layout.setCenter(new AnchorPane((Parent) fxmlLoader.load()));
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
```

I do not know a lot about JavaFX layouts. I am more of a backend guy, so I am at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Neither wrapping the fxml content in another `AnchorPane` which is added as center of another `BorderPane` for no obvious reason nor using the fxml content as root reproduces the error you described...

Comment: OMG that was it. I had copied the code in the Controller from another class that created a modal dialog. I missed removing the "new AnchorPane" code. You have unwittingly found the answer! :-)